# Is it safe to remove previous versions of the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

I've just installed the 3.5 .NET Framework and while doing some cleaning I've notice that I have a lot of older versions installed (1.1, 1.1 Hotfix(xxx), 2.0, 2.0 service pack etc...). I wonder if I can safely dispose of all of them or these are needed in case I run a lower version .net application.

Thanks in advance.

This is a duplicate of [Safe to uninstall .NET Framework 2.0 and 1.0 after installing 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385893/safe-to-uninstall-net-framework-2-0-and-1-0-after-installing-3-5)

Comment: I think the real question is: "Does it make sense to remove previous versions of the .NET framework? - I think the answer is "no", btw

Comment: This is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385893/safe-to-uninstall-net-framework-2-0-and-1-0-after-installing-3-5

Comment: yay, you're right, I didn't see that one while searching for answers, thanks. I'm closing myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a framework is needed for apps using this specific framework.
so if you are using 2.0 or 1.0 apps (or in the future), do not uninstall them - otherwise: you are free as a bird to do so :)

Answer (score 4):

No, apps made with the older frameworks will still need them installed.

Answer (score 4):

You will still need the older versions for an older .net app to run.

In addition, Versions 3.0 and 3.5 are actually no more than extensions to 2.0 so for 3.5 itself to work you still need to leave 2.0 installed.

Generally just not advisable to remove any of them.

Comment: aahhh ... yes, i forgot this one :) but try to uninstall 2.0 if you previously installed 3.0/3.5 - a msg will be shown with this info

Answer (score 4):

Imho, you can remove .NET 1.0/1.1 - I have removed it by myself and didn't saw any application was requiring it.

you cannot remove .NET 2.0 because 3.0/3.5 just extends the functionality of 2.0 - the biggest part of it is stilled contained into 2.0